# for input string:"" in build.gradle on apple M1

Tags: android, gradle

When I run my app use jdk_x86(jdk1.8.0_321.jdk), I can build success, but when I use jdk_arm(zulu-8.jdk), gradle sync error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/test/Work/Test/AlbumList/library/build.gradle' line: 29

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':library'.
> For input string: ""

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

the build gradle:

```
29:def revisionNumber = 'git rev-list HEAD --count'.execute().getText().trim().toInteger()
```

I find 'git rev-list HEAD --count' run in a error path, not run in current project path.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have gradle wrapper version 7.0+

I lost quite some time testing several M1 JDK distros and all presented the same behavior.

Turns out Gradle only added support to M1 on this version thus the error you're seeing